# How to run clojure koans in cursive

Tags: clojure, cursive

I want to run koans in cursive, I don't understand how to do that.

http://clojurekoans.com/

How can I run it?

Comment: The Koans doc state how to run them via lein and the Curive docs state how to run lein. So assuming you hit some roadblock trying this, please add what you have tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure koans suppor repl mode to run it enter the command at repl.

```
(exec "run")
```